# US marketed iPad Pro warranty in India

Tags: ipad, warranty, applecare

If I buy an iPad Pro in the US does it have a 1 year Apple warranty in India?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Apple products have International warranties but only in the countries where it has, it's own Stores. In India, there are no Apple-owned stores yet. They are Resellers authorized by Apple but they won't service your device because you won't possibly be taking it to Apple-owned stores. I hope this suffices your query.

https://www.apple.com/legal/warranty/products/ipad-english-a.html