# Can I get warranty on unlocked iphone 11 in India bought in US?

Tags: iphone, warranty

Iphone 11 is much cheaper in US in compare to India. One of my friend is currently there for some business work. I am aware about Apple providing global warranty now, But still want to get sure before I make a purchase.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30/is-apples-warranty-international and the linked and related questions. Feel free to close it as dupe yourself if you want.

Comment: Almost all the other answers are old, and global warranty get introduced recently. Thanks

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/370479/us-marketed-ipad-pro-warranty-in-india now I think it leans towards customer support.

Answer (score 1):

Usually its global warranty for one year. I had an issue with Mac bought in Europe and in India it was fixed for free.